# asp.net core 2 identity "Remember me" does not work

Tags: c#, asp.net-identity, asp.net-core-2.0

I have created a new asp.net core2 web application using Individual User Accounts - I'm new to asp.net core identity. I'm using VS 2017. I've made no change to the code generated by VS. I ran the project and registered a new user successfully. But when I login and check the "Remember me?" checkbox, then after signing out and trying to sign in again, It forgoes me and I must type my username and password again! So what is the problem?

Comment: `Remember me` doesn't mean what you think it means. It means 'if I close my browser and load it again will I still be logged in?'. Basically it enables a **permanent** cookie rather than a **session** cookie.

Comment: Thanks for your guide. I said i was new to Identity.

Comment: When you signed out then it doesn't remember you any more.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `LoginInputModel model` in **[HttpBody]** ==> it is contains Login data, so
and make sure the value  `model.RememberMe` is **true** Or not

```
[HttpPost]
[AllowAnonymous]
public async Task<IActionResult> doLogin(LoginInputModel model, string returnUrl = null)
{
  if (User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
  {

    return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
  }

  ViewData["ReturnUrl"] = returnUrl;
  if (ModelState.IsValid)
  {


    try {

    var result = await _signManager.PasswordSignInAsync(MyUser, model.Password, model.RememberMe, lockoutOnFailure: false);// ==>> model.RememberMe = true

    .
    .
    .
}
```

Comment: _signManager ==>  private SignInManager<ApplicationUser> _signManager;
 public AccountHomeController( SignInManager<ApplicationUser> signManager)
    {
      _signManager = signManager;

    }

Comment: If you run it using Visual Studio ... if you stooped debugging ... the cookies will be removed

Comment: Thanks for your attention to my question. By [mjwills](https://stackoverflow.com/users/34092/mjwills)'s comment,  I got that i was bad understood about **Remember me** function. But I will appreciate you if you help me to provide a facility for user to save his/her user/pass in client machine using cookies.